# Best/Correct way to call an Informix stored procedure via ADO.Net Command?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, informix

I have an Informix database which exposes some stored procedures, I have an abstracted data accessor that handles communicating with them but I have a problem with a null value.

Directly you can call:

```
execute procedure some_stored_procedure(1,2,NULL,3)
```

and get back correct results, I would rather there not be this nullable field, but it is out of my hands. Anyway I was originally trying to call it like so:

```
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandTypes.StoredProcedure
command.CommandText = "some_stored_procedure"
// Pass in the parameters
```

However doing that causes Informix to throw a syntax error, so instead I have been forced to go with the:

```
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "execute procedure some_stored_procedure(?,?,?,?)";
// Pass in parameters
```

Which works but never passes back correct results, and if I try and make parameter 3 null it gives another syntax error. Am I missing something or is there a better way to call these stored procedures?

Answer (score 2):

try parameterizing the parameters (you can use `OdbcParameters` if working with the odbcdriver) and then pass `DbNull.Value` where Null is required.

Try this:

```
var command = connection.CreateCommand(); 
command.CommandType = CommandTypes.Text;
command.CommandText = "call some_stored_procedure(?,?,?,?)";

command.Parameters.Add(param); //add all your parameters.
```

Answer (score 0):

Format the query as follow:

```
        strQuery = string.Format("EXECUTE PROCEDURE Cronos_UpdateStateLegacyProduct ({0})", oValidityProducts.PurchaseId);

        OdbcConnection oConnection = new OdbcConnection(this.strConnectionString);
        OdbcCommand oCommand = new OdbcCommand();
        oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        oCommand.CommandText = strQuery;
        oCommand.Connection = oConnection;

        oConnection.Open();

        intResult = oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Best Regards

Answer (score -1):

In case you are using an ODBC connection, when using `CommandType.StoredProcedure` you must use a diferent syntax for the procedure's name. In your case:

```
CommandText = "{ CALL some_stored_procedure(?,?,?,?)}"
```

Check this link for more information: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310130